# Python , MYSQL database

Tags: python, mysql

i have a table that records the attendance of students. The table have 4 columns , one for the student ID and the other are for week1 ,week2 and week3 (All the columns are integers). The attendance is recorded by entering only 1 for the certain week ( or zero if he was absent) . My problem is here , when i want to add the attendance i use the update statement as follow :

```
week_number=input('enter the week ( week1/week2/week3') 
id=int(input('enter student ID'))
sat="UPDATE Attendance2 SET %s=1 WHERE ID=%s "
cur.execute(sat, (week_number,id,))
conn.commit()
```

As you can see ,I don't know what the column that the user will refer to ( it is a variable ) , so i have used `%s` behind the SET, but it is wrong.

Here is the error :

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''week1'=1 WHERE ID=300' at line 1
```

Any help please ? How do i write a variable column name in a execute statement ?

Note that i am updating only the attended students , that's why there is 1 in the `UPDATE` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, it's supposed to be ok to surround keys with quotes. But as you say that all datatypes are integers, your values have no issues.

And because it says this is a syntax error (and not column issue, what it would yell if it was not finding `week1`), it leads me to believe the issues actually are your quotes, which if not expected by mysql's SQL grammar, it would indeed yell about a syntax issue.

```
mysql […] near ''week1'=1 WHERE ID=300' at line 1
                ^
```

What makes a python string gets surrounded by single quotes? It's the `repr()` version of the string, the one you get when you type a string on the REPL:

```
>>> x = '42'
>>> x
'42'
>>> print(repr(x))
'42'
>>> print(x)
42
```

I'm not sure why this issue would happen to you. A good ideais to use the python form of formatting strings, and run:

```
sat="UPDATE Attendance2 SET {}=1 WHERE ID={}".format(week_number, id)
```

if it still happens, you can try to force typing of `week_number` into a `str()`, using `str(week_number)`.

Talking about formatting strings, you might want to enforce the typing, so you avoid surprises:

```
sat="UPDATE Attendance2 SET {:s}=1 WHERE ID={:d}".format(str(week_number), int(id))
```

which will make sure `week_number` is a valid string and formatted as a string, and `id` is a valid integer and formatted as an integer.

Nota Bene: avoid using `id` in your code, which is a python reserved keyword, and instead use `_id`, `ident` or `idx`. It's always a good idea to avoid shadowing global python keywords.

HTH

Comment: Hmm… Looks like Bobby Tables might cause some havoc here.

Comment: everybody ♥ bobby tables! BTW @ahmed never forget to check and protect your inputs from possible injection. In your code, if an user inputs something like `; DELETE FROM Attendance2 WHERE 1=1; --` you might be screwed. And don't try to be smart and reinvent the wheel, use existing known to work libraries to proctect you against it, or use a proper ORM like SQLAlchemy.

Comment: I am just a beginner this my first python and MYSQL code  . Thank you very much for your advice .

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sat="UPDATE Attendance2 SET " + week_number + "='1' WHERE ID='" + student_id + "'"
cur.execute(sat)
...
```

hope this helps ^^-d

PS: It is easier to test the code if you set the variables week_number and student_id "hardwired", e.g.:

```
week_number = "week1"
student_id = "1"
```

PPS: The way you design your table is a bit redundant which may lead to update errors in the future. It might e.g. be better to have a 2 column table with the student_id and attended_week(as 1,2,3).

Comment: Thanky ou very much for your help :) . Unfortenetly , the first option gives me this error : enter week ( week1/week2/week3)week1
enter student ID300
Traceback (most recent call last):
 <module>
    sat="UPDATE Attendance2 SET " + week_number + "='1' WHERE ID='" + id + "'"
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitlyThe second option gives me this error : mysql.connector.errors. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''week1'='1' WHERE ID='300'' at line 1